# Restart server and poll for started service

Tags: powershell

If I was to create a script to restart a server and wait for a started service `SERVICE123 - NODE1` to come back up, how would I do this?

I have the following:

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName COMPUTER123456 wait -For SERVICE123 - NODE1 -Timeout 400 -Delay 5
```

If not, is there a script I could use to poll for a started service only? I would like it to sit for 20 minutes or so until this service node is up and running.

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 0):

To see if a Service is running you can use the invoke Command. And execute the 
cmdlet get-service on the machine.

```
$service =  Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER123456 -ScriptBlock { Get-Service -Name $args[0] } -ArgumentList "Service123"
```

via `$service.Status` you can see if the Service is Running or Stopped.

Normaly it should work with your code and the restart-Computer cmdlet,
what is the error, is there any error given. Why does your code not work?

I have an idea, you have to put the hyphen to the parameter 'wait' = `-Wait`

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName COMPUTER123456 -Wait -For "SERVICE123 - NODE1" -Timeout 400 -Delay 5
```

Have a look at [MSTechnet](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849837.aspx)
In example 6 you see exactly what you need.

Greets Eldo.Ob

Comment: In addition to adding the missing hyphen on the parameter `-Wait` you must put the service name in quotes.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thank you :) You're right - I corrected it.